# PowerMockito spy running actual private method

Tags: java, junit, mocking

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( ClassWithPrivate.class  )
public class Testy{

   @Test
   public void testSOmething(){
         String response = "something";
        ClassWithPrivate  some = PowerMockito.spy(new ClassWithPrivate("someArg"));
        PowerMockito.doReturn(response).when(some,PowerMockito.method(ClassWithPrivate.class,"privateMethod",String.class)).withArguments(anyString();

    }
}
```

I'm not very familiar with PowerMockito, but is this normal that when the doReturn line runs it will actualy make a call to privateMethod.

For me the issue is that I want to mock the privateMethod,  because without mocking it will throw a exception. Currently my test will be closed after the doReturn line, because an exception is thrown from the privateMethod.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

`PowerMockito.doReturn(response).when(some, "privateMethod", anyString());`

Comment: I would also try if it works without argument matcher (e.g. "concereteString" insted of anyString()).